# Remove all parent html blocks exept one with js / jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have div box:

```
 <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
        <dl class="sp-methods"> 
        <dt>Flat Rate</dt>
                <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate" value="flatrate_flatrate" name="shipping_method">
                        <label for="s_method_flatrate_flatrate">Fixed<span class="price">5,00&nbsp;US$</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </dd> 

           <dt>Delivery with Post Station</dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_postservice_postservice" value="postservice_postservice" name="shipping_method">
                        <label for="s_method_postservice_postservice">PostService<span class="price">2,00&nbsp;US$</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

I`m traying with jQuery set all inputs prop disabled true, exept  input#s_method_postservice_postservice dd block.
So all inputs need set to disabled exept 'input#s_method_postservice_postservice.

My Code:

```
$( "input[name=shipping_method]:not('input#s_method_postservice_postservice')" ).prop('disabled', true );`
```

But nothing works!
Please help how to do that?

Comment: if nothing else, you can always just disable ALL of the inputs, then explicitly enable the one you want to leave active.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/7rKdK/

Comment: Hmm, Interesting.. Does there is any method to hide another dd and dt blocks?